# Converting one row in a pandas df to multiple by splitting a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in which the row is of the format.

```
Index Name Categories
 0     bob  a,b,c,d
 1    sally b,d,f
```

etc.

And i want this in the format

```
name categories
bob     a
        b
        c
        d
sally   b
        d
        f
```

Does anyone know a smart way to split that into rows about that elements' commas?

Cheers

I have considered the option of breaking down the database and rebuilding a new one, i'm capable of that but this will ultimately be implemented on a 12,000,000 row database and I am looking for a more straightforward approach.

Comment: `df.set_index('Name')['Categories'].str.split(",").explode()` ?

Comment: Perfect, worked thanks